# How can I configure 2 different subnets within one network and enable them to communicate with one another

Tags: networking, subnet

1. Please can the 255.255.255.0 mask communicate with the 255.255.0.0 mask.
2. can IP 192.168.100.1 and IP 192.168.200.1 exist within the 255.255.255.0 network?

I feel like the impact of the 255.0 subnet will not permit me to move 100.1 to 200.1 network.
I just want someone who has tried such to please educate me.
I am using Cisco packet tracer.

Comment: Subnetting is dividing a network into multiple networks (subnets) that are within the address range of the original network. Routers route between networks, so you will need to route between the new networks. See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for a full explanation about how it works. Be sure to understand both parts (two answers). Part 1 gives you the IPv4 math, and Part 2 uses the math to explain subnetting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood you correctly, but if you wanna reach the .100 subnet from your .200 and vice versa you have to configure a route from one subnet to another.

To configure a such route you need the network address, the subnet mask and the ip address of your gateway(your router I guess).

If both subnets are directly connected to your router, you have nothing to do on your router and just add the route on your hosts.
Then your network looks similar to this (Maybe the hosts are connected to aswitch which is then connected to the router):
[image]

It depends on your host how to add a route. On linux you can use the `ip` command or use the GUI.